# Is it possible to render POIs/landmarks from Postgres/postgis DB using google Map like icons?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, google-maps, icon

Is it possible to render POIs/landmarks from Postgres/postgis DB using google Map like icons? Any readily available icon sets?

Comment: Map icons can be stored in postgres - icon set http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/

Comment: Geoserver + PostGIS + SLD = Best Solution!!!

Comment: Please provide clear details on what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can render your data using a middleware like [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org).

Regarding your icon set request, first result doing a simple Google search

http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/

Have you done any research at all?

This [other](https://www.mapbox.com/maki/) from MapBox is nice also.

Comment: I got this collection already. But it not as good as Google have. :)